# Get the grandchild of an element with specific ID

Tags: javascript

I have the following :

```
<div id="first">
  <div id="second">
    <button id="third"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The DIV with ID of `first` will never change it's ID but `second` and `third` might change.

If it never changed I'd use something the following to target `third` :

```
submission = document.getElementById("third");
```

However, using `first`, how would I access it now? I've tried the following but get a different result back than the above (which is what I need)

```
submission = document.querySelectorAll("div#first div button");
```

This seems to work but doesn't look clean :

```
document.getElementById("first").children[0].children[0];
```

Comment: In your examples you are using vanilla JS, but you tagged it as jquery?

Comment: In what way might the "*`second` and `third`...change*"?

Comment: They might be any other value

Comment: @tgdn sorry, I hope you can forgive me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `querySelector()` if you want to get the `button` element instead of `querySelectorAll()` that will return a set of elements that fits the selector :

```
submission = document.querySelector("div#first div button");
```

Hope this helps.

```js
console.log( document.getElementById("third") );
console.log( document.querySelector("div#first div button") );
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <div id="second">
    <button id="third"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('#first> div> button');
var btn1 = document.querySelector('#first> div> button');

console.dir(btn)
console.dir(btn1)
```

```html
<div id="first">
    <div id="second">
      <button id="third"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you do `document.querySelectorAll` then this will return `Array` of `NodeLists` and If you do `document.querySelector` then it will return the specific element

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('#first> div> button');
var btn1 = document.querySelector('#first> div> button');

console.dir(btn)
console.dir(btn1)
```